# difference between continuous functional calculus and borel functional calculus

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

When $N$ is a normal operator on $H$ with spectral measure $E$,let $B(\sigma(N))$ be the $C^*$ algebra of bounded Borel functions on $\sigma(N)$, we have the map $\psi\mapsto \psi(N)$, which is a representation of the $C^*$ algebra $B(\sigma(N))$.

But  we also have the map from $C(\sigma(N))\to B(H)$, $\psi \mapsto \psi (N)$. Is the Borel functional calculus an extension of continuous functional calculus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in both cases they are faithful representations that map the identity function to $N$. So they agree on polynomials. Being continuous, they agree on continuous functions.